# Convert a double array to Double ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist

When I try to convert a double array to a Double arrayList I got the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [D cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Below is my code.

```
double [] firstValueArray ;
```

`ArrayList   <Double> firstValueList = new ArrayList (Arrays.asList(firstValueArray));`

I am comparing this list with another list and assign the result to another double variable.

Please let me know the reason for this error.

Comment: `for(doule d : doubleArray) arrayList.add(d);`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Alas, `Arrays.asList(..)` doesn't work with primitives. Apache commons-lang has

```
Double[] doubleArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(durationValueArray);
List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(doubleArray);
```

Answer (score 36):

Using Java 8 Streams API this is achieved with

```
DoubleStream.of(doublesArray).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Since java 16 this became a bit more concise:

```
DoubleStream.of(doublesArray).boxed().toList();
```

If returning an `ArrayList` as an implementation is required then use

```
DoubleStream.of(doublesArray).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

This one-liner doesn't require any additional libraries.

Answer (score 23):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s version is even shorter:

```
List<Double> list = Doubles.asList(doubleArray);
```

**Reference:**

- [`Doubles.asList(double ...)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#asList%28double...%29)

**Note:** This is a varargs method. All varargs methods can be called using an array of the same type (but not of the corresponding boxed / unboxed type!!). These two calls are equivalent:

```
Doubles.asList(new double[]{1d,2d});
Doubles.asList(1d,2d);
```

Also, the Guava version doesn't do a full traverse, it's a live List view of the primitive array, converting primitives to Objects only when they are accessed.

Comment: What is varargs method? and how the two calls are equivalent?

Comment: @sunny the mechanism is described here: [Java Tutorial: Arbitrary Number of Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs). The key phrase is "It's a shortcut to creating an array manually"

Comment: It seems that the list returned by `Doubles.asList(double... backingArray)`, does not allow any changes, such as adding elements to the list using `add` or `addAll`. Updated link to doc: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html

Comment: @SayanPal yes, by design. that's actually what these Lists have in common with those created by the standard library's `Arrays.asList(elements)`. If you need to add elements, copy the list to an ArrayList or LinkedList: `new ArrayList<>(Doubles.asList(1.0d, 2.0d))`

Answer (score 5):

Credit to bestsss for the comment which should be the answer:

```
ArrayList<Double> firstValueList = new ArrayList<Double>();
for(double d : firstValueArray) firstValueList.add(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

…or with Java 1.7:

```
double[] firstValueArray = new double[] {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};

ArrayList<Double> list = DoubleStream.of( firstValueArray ).boxed().collect(
    Collectors.toCollection( new Supplier<ArrayList<Double>>() {
      public ArrayList<Double> get() {
        return( new ArrayList<Double>() );
      }
    } ) );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a valid answer for Java 7. `java.util.stream.DoubleStream` and `java.util.function.Supplier` were introduced in 1.8.