# java generics problem when converting from array to vector

Tags: java, arrays, generics, vector

Why is this not allowed? arr is a double[].

```
Vector<Double> v = new Vector<Double>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

I get a unrecognized constructor error. It thinks i'm trying to use the `Vector(java.util.List<double[]>)` constructor which seems odd cuz why would it be a list of double[]s? It compiles if i make it this

```
Vector<Double> v = new Vector(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

but then I get a warning about unchecked assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `Double` is not the same as `double` in Java.

[Arrays.asList doesn't work with primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178854/convert-a-double-array-to-double-arraylist/5178920#5178920), so when you're calling it with a `double[]` as its first parameter, it thinks you're passing in the array itself as the first argument in the `...`-style argument list. Therefore, `Arrays.asList` returns a List of `double[]`, containing only a single element: the `double[]` that you passed in.

Answer (score 1):

Generics like `List<double>` do not permit primitive types and this is why your program is failing.

You need to iterate the array and fill up your collection item by item. Or you can use the [ArrayUtils.toObject()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28double%5b%5d%29) method to convert from `double[]` to `Double[]`. That class is found int the [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) library.

Comment: so is there no easy (without having to iterate over each item) way to convert an array into a vector?

Comment: @jhlu87 Added a reference to a utility method that is ready to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, 'double' is a primitive type, like 'int' or 'char'. 'Double' is a class type. You can make a vector of . Change the original array to be an array of 'Double's, not 'double's.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList(T... a)` doesn't work as expected with primitive arrays, because generics and primitives don't get along very well.  The compiler is using `double[]` for `T`, which is why `Arrays.asList` is returning a `List<double[]>`.

I think the shortest code to get what you want is:

```
Vector<Double> v = new Vector<Double>(arr.length);
for (double d : arr) v.add(d);
```