# java - convert primitive double array to collection

Tags: java

I'm looking to have an array of floats(doubles) & integers as below -

```
double[] myArr = {0, 0, 95, 9.5, 19, 610.5, 1217, 5.14, 4038.66, 10.23, 7961, 828, 199858, 37325.3};
```

I then have this function that returns the max & min

```
    public static void getMaxArrVal(double[] myArr) {           

        myCol = /* Code to convert myarr to collection should come here */
        System.out.println(Collections.min(myCol ));
        System.out.println(Collections.max(myCol ));
    }
}

getMaxArrVal(myArr);
```

I'm having problems converting primitive data type to a collection.I tried converting this to double list, tried by converting myArr to char/String to check a few things but nothing has worked obviously.

I keep seeing the compilation error of primitive data type. I did try `Double` too but no luck.

How could I possibly convert the array to collection & calculate min/max on this one. I'd appreciate any help her please.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178854/convert-a-double-array-to-double-arraylist#5178920

Comment: @prasad is correct; this question is essentially an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works nicely with Java 8:

```
Arrays.stream(myArr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Any `Collection` may be used instead of `ArrayList`, of course. The code I have here may actually be simplified to `Collectors.toList()`.

Also, as noted in [@nukie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35825129/3529323), `DoubleStream` has its own `min()` and `max()` methods, rendering the conversion useless. Merely use two streams created using `Arrays.stream(myArr)` and call these methods.

Answer (score 2):

Guava comes with nice solution

```
Lists.newArrayList(double[])
```

Answer (score 1):

if you run this code at java8 you can try lambdas:

```
Arrays.stream(myArr).max();
```

and

```
Arrays.stream(myArr).max();
```

Comment: Please check your spelling, and also your code. This won't work because primitive streams like the generated `DoubleStream` don't accept `Collector`s in their `collect()` method. Stream is not spelt straem.

Comment: thank you for remark! this was unexpected for me that DoubleStream not provide collect(Collector) method )

Comment: It wouldn't make much sense, as `Collector`s are generic and you can't have a `Collector<double, X, X>`. Still, we all wish things like this could be possible sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

```
double[] primitives = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
List<Double> objects = new ArrayList<>();
for(double num : primitives) {
    objects.add(num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Double [] myArr = {0., 0., 95., 9.5, 19., 610.5, 1217., 5.14, 4038.66, 10.23,  7961., 828., 199858., 37325.3};      

    Double min = Arrays.stream(myArr).min(Comparator.<Double>naturalOrder()).get();
    Double max = Arrays.stream(myArr).max(Comparator.<Double>naturalOrder()).get();

    System.out.println(min);
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

If you don't need collection to anything else, except find `max` and `min`, create stream right from array. In this case you don't need create separate collection at all.

Comment: Do not forget a `Stream` object can only be used once. Just use `Arrays.stream(myArr)` twice...

Comment: @YassinHajaj I did. And you're right. Thanx for comment.

Comment: Thank you Ken. I prefer `double` as I've written quite a lot of code with that type. So `Double` doesn't quite work in this situation. However, this is a good future reference for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using Arrays.sort will sort your array in ascending order. Therefore, you know the min will be the first element of your array, myArr[0], and your max will be the last element in your array myArr[myArr.length-1].

```
double[] myArr = {0, 0, 95, 9.5, 19, 610.5, 1217, 5.14, 4038.66, 10.23, 7961,  828, 199858, 37325.3};
Arrays.sort(myArr);
System.out.println(myArr[0]);
System.out.println(myArr[myArr.length-1]);
```

The following will result in

0.0 <-- min

199858.0 <-- max

Comment: This approach will change original array's order. But if OP don't cares - perfect solution.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I need the array order to remain the same.